# Android - Autofit image in ImageView?

Tags: android

I will be displaying an image in an ImageView that will always be much higher and wider than the size of the screen. Is there a simple way to scale the image down so that it fills the ImageView exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting up the scale type in the xml, i believe it scaleXY is the one you are looking for [scale types](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

```
<ImageView
android:scaleType="scaleXY"
android:src="@drawable/my_image"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading the view in XML, the android:scaleType parameter should do the trick.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType