# stretch imagebuttons in linearlayout to use available space

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout, android-linearlayout, imagebutton

I've been playing with some XML in order to achieve the following;

first row is a banner (works fine). Then; I have 3 buttons on each row. I want the buttons to take up all horizontal space (so; screen width diveded by 3). Also, the images on the buttons should resize to that width, without changing aspect ratio!. How can this be done?

Next; if I add rows of ImageButtons, how should I 'shell' the LinearLayouts in a scrollview to maintain the width distribution for 3 buttons?

thnx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/blogbanner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/test_banner_ad" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/trololo" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:src="@drawable/scout" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/painting" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/whoop" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/drown" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/love" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/shredder" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/frog" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/yeah03" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the 3 buttons of each row into another horizontal layout, then use the "[weight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_weight)" attribute to define their widths.

The images would need to have dimensions "fill_parent" & use [scaleXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873748/android-autofit-image-in-imageview).

Comment: Do I choose fill parent for the width and height? Or one of them?.. I'm trying, but images don't keep aspect ratio, they're being streched..also, scaleXY doesn't exist? using FitXY now, but it stretches images..

Comment: Yes,both.
Sorry, I thought you wanted them stretched. To maintain the ratio use:
    android:scaleType="CENTER_INSIDE"
or
    android:scaleType="CENTER_CROP"

Comment: see here for more info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html